# Using the range(len) instead of just (var)

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

> Write a program that takes in a string input of names and returns an email address. For names with both letters and alphabets, end with `@yahoo.com`. For names that have only alphabets, return with `@gmail.com`

My code:

```
names = input().split()

ending_g = '@gmail.com'

ending_y = '@yahoo.com'

for i in range(len(names)): [MY QUESTION PERTAINS TO THIS LINE]

  if names[i].isalpha() == True:

    print(names[i],ending_g)

  else:

   print(names[i],ending_y)
```

For the `for` loop, when I have it like that it works fine. 1) Why doesn't work when I have it as `for I in (names):`?

The error it returns is that `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`. I thought that using `.split()` puts each element into the list with its own index value.

2. is the extra `range(len)` only necessary when the input is a string? Because when an input is a string getting converted into a float (example below) it works properly.

ex:

```
for i in score():
    scores[i] = float(scores[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, there's usually no need for explicit indexing of iterables. So don't use an index variable. You can just do

```
names = input().split()

ending_g = '@gmail.com'
ending_y = '@yahoo.com'

for n in names:
    addr = n + (ending_g if n.isalpha() else ending_y)
    print(addr)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `for name in names:` - `name` is  NOT an integer number - and indexes into lists mus be integers - that is exactly  what the error tells you ... `name` is one of your strings:

```
names = "A B C2 42".split()

for name in names:  
    if name.isalpha():
        print(name, ".alpha", sep = "")
    else:
        print(name, ".number", sep = "")
```

Output:

```
A.alpha  
B.alpha  
C2.number
42.number
```

---

Treating a string as an index is what produces your error:

```
names = "A B C".split()

for name in names:  
    if names[name].isalpha():   # makes no sense as name is not an index
        print(name, ".alpha", sep="")
```

> ```
> Exception has occurred: TypeError
> list indices must be integers or slices, not str
> File "whatever", line 4, in <module>
>     if names[name].isalpha() == True:
> ```